# Dynamic Association in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create a dynamic association in sequelize.
Lets say I have users which belong to a project.
These users take different roles in the project.
E.g. some users are developers others are architects etc.

```
var User = sequelize.define("user", {...})
var Project = sequelize.define("project", {...})

var ProjectUser = Project.hasMany(Users)
```

I know that I could just add them as:

```
Project.hasMany(User, { as: "developers"})
...
```

I have all roles in a seperate table.

```
var Role = sequelize.define("role", {...})
```

How can I make the association depending on the role?
Something like:

```
var UserProject("userProject", {
   userId: ...,
   roleId: ....,
   projectId: ...
})

Project.hasMany(User, { through: UserProject })
```

Answer (score 2):

I read in the sequelize documentation that you can do something like this.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/

UPDATE:

Actually this gives me the possibility to do what I want, but 
I don't know how to query the data then.

For example how do I know which role the user than has, especially in the instance of the project.

```
sequelize.define("project", { }, {
    instanceMethods: {
        getPublicRepresentation() {
            this.users //how do I know the role of the user here?
        }
    }
})
```

Another problem I am still running into is, when I want to query.

```
Project.findAll({
    include: {
        model: User
    }
})
```

How do I get the where role equals ... in?